# Who's driving this floating monowheel, in Marvel's Civil War: Frontline?

Tags: marvel, comics, marvel-civil-war

I've just seen this in the foreground of one of the panels, with the speaking characters seemingly oblivious.

[image: Kayak pestering]

In the following panel it looks like he's being chased by the police:

[image: police chase]

But he looks super-powered.

Who is it?

Comment: I misread "this kayaker" as "the kayaker", as in the name of a super hero.  I am dissapoint.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It looks like [The Big Wheel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Wheel_(comics)). Same wheel motif with the funny waldo-arms on the wheel, same green armor.

[image: The Big Wheel vs Rocket Racer]

> You're a dead man racer, courtesy of...
>
> What... Weele,  hey it can't be you!

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Wheel_(comics))

> Jackson Weele is a businessman who has embezzled from his company. Fearing that he might be caught, he hires a youthful criminal, Rocket Racer, to steal the evidence that incriminates him. However, Rocket Racer opts to use the evidence to blackmail Weele instead. Despairing, Weele tries to commit suicide, but Rocket Racer prevents him from doing so. However, Racer is not particularly kind to Weele, disparagingly referring to him as "Big Weele". Humiliated by Rocket Racer's taunts, Weele visits the mechanical genius and underworld supplier the Tinkerer, who the Rocket Racer boasted had upgraded his equipment. At Weele's urging, the Tinkerer creates a large metal wheel that can climb up buildings, complete with guns and waldo-arms.

And indeed, he showed up in *Civil War: Frontline*:

> During the "Civil War" storyline, Big Wheel is shown being chased by the Harbor Patrol, implying that he returned to super-heroics despite the doubts he harbored in Spider-Man Unlimited.
>
> In a later issue, he is brought in by Spider-Man and Iron Man concerning black market connections Iron Man believes may have aided Ezekiel Stane.
>
> Jackson later returns in a more jagged version of his Big Wheel machine and joins Blackout and other villains in a mission to kill Ghost Rider

Comment: Brilliant!  I wonder why he's in this panel though?

Comment: ^_^ Because the writers and artists love cameos of obscure characters to show that they're hep to history?

Comment: +1 - but wow that is the laziest sounding origin story

Comment: They were talking about embezzlement on an earlier panel,  maybe it was related

Comment: I thought you were talking about the guy's arms with "funny grabby arms". Amusing few moments figuring that out.

Comment: @DCShannon: :-P No. I meant the Waldoes on the sides. I will amend.

Comment: where are the quotations from?

Comment: @AShelly: Wikipedia, same place I linked his name to.